# Telephone services? Receive phone call and send JSON to webservice

Tags: json, web-services, telephony

Does anyone know of a service that can receive a phone call, in the UK, and on receipt of that call, send a `JSON` payload to a specified webservice?

The minimum data to be sent would be the telephone number of the caller and a timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a android phone system. When you get a call you can get the details out of it and can form a json object. And you can send to any webservices using popular webservices frameworks for android.

Comment: So this would mean having an android phone plugged in all the time? It could work, but I'd rather find a service that can do this rather than self-host

Answer (score 1):

Any of the cloud telephony providers can handle this, with some simple front end coding on your part. Check out [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/), [Tropo](https://www.tropo.com/), or [Plivo](https://www.plivo.com/), these services should be able to provide UK phone numbers.

Comment: I think I can see how Twilio can do it witht he twiML language